# How to preserve &amp; in <pre><code>

Tags: php, html, wordpress, escaping, markup

I am having trouble preserving an ampersand in a code example on my blog, because all HTML entities start with &.

Any tips?

For example:

```
<pre>
<code>
<?php 
$pageTitle = str_replace('&', ' &amp;', $page->attributes()->title);
?>
</code>
</pre>
```

Renders as:

```
<?php 
$pageTitle = str_replace('&', '&', $page->attributes()->title);
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the *best* option, but one workaround is to double-escape it:

```
str_replace('&', ' &amp;amp;', $page->attributes()->title);
```

This way, the first `&amp;` shows up as a literal ampersand, then the remaining `amp;` shows up as literal text.

Comment: In fact, that is how Stack Overflow rendered it in the question.

Comment: hahaaaaa... that is so obvious and yet I didn't think of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode the string with  htmlentities(). For example,

```
<pre>
<code>
<?php
echo htmlentities("$pageTitle = str_replace('&', ' &amp;', $page->attributes()->title)");
?>
</code>
</pre>
```